# angularjs resolving dependencies that are promises in controllers

Tags: angularjs

I thought that if a dependency is promise it will not get passed to controller sooner as it is  resolved. However, using 1.1.4 (tahts likely not the cause) I found out its not so. I know how to force promise to be reoslved if this is dependecy to the current *view* controller. However , in my case the controller is defined as part of ngInclude. How to force it to resolve before controller is loaded?

Comment: could you set up fiddle or plunker demo to understand your code in better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this when specifying routing via routeProvider and using resolve property in route definition ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)). Not sure if there is other way to do this.

Comment: I know abour routeProviders abilities. They inspired me to ask this question. If routeProvider can do it, can we do it where we need it?

Comment: e.g. in agular-ui-bootstrap there is a ui-dialog that can load a template - what if that template has got a controller that depends on something that needs to be resolved.